# Subcaption of figures in a table

Tags: tables, subfloats, tabularx, subcaption

There are two ways I would like to describe the figures in the table: put sub caption under each figure (preferred) or insert the description directly in the figure.

To create a table of figures, I wrote the following code:

```
\begin{sidewaystable}[!htbp]
\label{tab:gr}
\centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}>{\bfseries}c*{9}{X}@{}}

  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{A1}&
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{A2} & 
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{A3} & 
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{A4} \\

  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{B1} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{B2} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{B3} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{B4} \\

  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/C1} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/C2} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/C3} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/C4} \\

  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/D1} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/D2} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/D3} &
  \includegraphics[width=2.2in,height=1.8in]{fig/D4} \\
  \end{tabularx}
  \caption{The main caption of the table.}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image]

Because I got different meanings of figures given a row, I want to put individual description under (right to, in this case) each figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `\subcaption` command from the package with the same name to add a caption for each sufigure.

There is a problem with using subcaptions inside a `tabularx`, see [this bug report at SourceForge](http://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/23/), so it's better to use a regular `tabular` with `p` columns.

Notes about the code:

- The `\label` always has to be placed *after* (or within) the `\caption`.
- I reduced the size of the images a bit, they need to be smaller to be able to fit in the page, due to the extra space added by the subcaptions.
  (Even with my adjustment the table may wider than the text block, depending on your settings.)
- A space between the image and the subcaption seems to introduce extra vertical spacing. I.e., instead of

  ```
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image} \subcaption{Text}
  ```

  write

  ```
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image}\subcaption{Text}
  ```
- To further compress the table vertically, you can add `\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}`  right before the `tabular`. You can also move the subcaption closer to the images with `\captionsetup[subtable]{aboveskip=2pt}`. These are in the code, but commented.

---

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{rotating}    
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}%
%\renewcommand\arraystretch{0}
%\captionsetup[subtable]{aboveskip=2pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}*{4}{p{1.8in}}@{}}
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-a}\subcaption{Text} & 
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-b}\subcaption{Text} & 
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-c}\subcaption{Text} \\

  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-a}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-b}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-c}\subcaption{Text} \\

  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-a}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-b}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-c}\subcaption{Text} \\

  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-a}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-b}\subcaption{Text} &
  \includegraphics[width=1.8in,height=1.2in]{example-image-c}\subcaption{Text} \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{The main caption of the table.}
\label{tab:gr}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! How to reduce the space between subcaption and the figures in next row in this case?

Comment: @Fred Adding `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0.1}` after the `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{2pt}` helps a bit.

Comment: Is there anyway I can reduce the space significantly? Since each figure should have space to be displayed properly, the size of it should not be too small thus the caption can't occupy too much.

Comment: @Fred I don't actually know. By the way, is there any text in the subcaptions, or are they empty, so you just get the number? If the latter, consider adding the numbers/letters to the images themselves, and add `\phantomsubcaption`s for cross referencing (see the `subcaption` manual).

Comment: Regarding the wrong table number, see https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/23/  But you could put a `\refstepcounter{table}` in front of the `tabularx` environment and cross your fingers anyway.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thanks! I switched to `tabular` instead, `tabularx` isn't really necessary in this case anyway.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thank you! I've been confused with the wrong numbering.